# install ".run" programs with automatic yes/ok/... option

Tags: linux, shell, administration, sh, remote-administration

When I install packages in linux environment I can set the automatic 'yes' option, for example

```
yum -y install ...
```

or

```
apt-get -y install...
```

Is there a way to do the same but for ".run" programs. For example as,

```
sudo sh a.run -y
```

So that whenever it asks yes/no it automatically selects yes, whenever it asks for ok/cancel it selects ok, and so on...

thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a .run command is simply a set of commands that are going to be run by sh. A particular .run file might take a -y option but in general you can't count on it. If you need to automate some stuff, consider using [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Comment: Can you put an example for this case (.run)? thanks